# Trying to hide image on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, element

I'm trying to hide the header image of https://gambiaschoolsupport.org/ on mobile devices.

I've used what I think is the correct CSS and when I preview the site in a virtual small screen the image is hidden.

```
   }
   @media (max-width: 768px) {
   .header-image {
   display:none;
   }
```

But when I view the site on an actual mobile device, the image is still there! What is going on?

Comment: If thats exactly the code you have, then you have `}` in a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site and found that your internal style tag contains `display:block` for `.header-image` class. Remove that and check. But before you do so, also remove `display:none` from `.header-image` class which is given in https://gambiaschoolsupport.org/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_de8fa02bd732efd9e22723257049a7e0.css. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have to confess I'm not sure how to do as you suggest. Not sure where to find the internal style tag and where to go to remove the display:none from the .header-image class. Can this be done by adding custom CSS?

Comment: search for all instances of .header-image in your code so that you will find it. Because even if you add custom css, you will be writing internal style tag only. which will be in addition to previous one. So I would recommend removing the once which is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Media screen

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
```